# При изменении данных в первом вложенном массиве изменяются данных и во втором

Tags: python-3.x, массивы

```py
start = [int(input()) for i in range(int(input()))]
arr = [start, start]
print(arr)
arr[0][0] += 5
print(arr, start)
```

При выполнении блока кода выше на выходе я получаю изменения не только в arr[0], но и в arr[1] и в start:

```
3
10
10
10
[[10, 10, 10], [10, 10, 10]]
[[15, 10, 10], [15, 10, 10]] [15, 10, 10]
```

Отсюда вопрос, как мне избежать лишних изменений, учитывая тот факт, что массив arr создаётся из двух start'ов

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У Вас это один и тот же массив.

---

```
arr = [start, start.copy()]
```

или

```
arr = [start.copy(), start.copy()]
```